# declaring the mode an emacs file should be opened in

Tags: emacs

how can I write, as a comment within a file, the mode that this particular file should be opened with in emacs?  for example, suppose I have a script called "foo".  In the body of foo, I'd like to put something like:

```
# sh-mode
# rest of my script here...
```

to emacs that "sh-mode" should be used when "foo" is opened in emacs.  Note, I don't want to do this by file extension from .emacs.  The point here is that the filename of "foo" does not say what type of file it is -- I want that to be specified from within the file itself.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I usually add something like:

```
# -*- mode: sh -*-
```

at the top of the file.  See the [emacs documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) for more information.

Comment: you can also add

    ### Local Variables:
    ### mode: latex
    ### End:`


at the end of the file

Comment: Also note the `sh-shell` variable can be used to set the name of the shell: `# -*- mode: sh; sh-shell: bash -*-`

Answer (score 9):

Note also that Emacs will also correctly identify the type of the file if the first line is a hash-bang comment, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 5):

you can specify file local variable that emacs uses in either the first or second line of any file(and more).

For more details see: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables

So for your case you can use:

```
# -*- mode: sh; -*-
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Also see magic-mode-alist.

```
magic-mode-alist is a variable defined in `files.el'.

Documentation:
Alist of buffer beginnings vs. corresponding major mode functions.
Each element looks like (REGEXP . FUNCTION) or (MATCH-FUNCTION . FUNCTION).
After visiting a file, if REGEXP matches the text at the beginning of the
buffer, or calling MATCH-FUNCTION returns non-nil, `normal-mode' will
call FUNCTION rather than allowing `auto-mode-alist' to decide the buffer's
major mode.

If FUNCTION is nil, then it is not called.  (That is a way of saying
"allow `auto-mode-alist' to decide for these files.")
```